# Associating a string with a derived class

Tags: c++, object-oriented, comparative-review, memory-optimization, casting

I am using the following code to get a string that is associated with the class of an instance:

```
std::string gate = 
    dynamic_cast<AND*>(pComponent) != nullptr ? "AND" :
    dynamic_cast<NAND*>(pComponent) != nullptr ? "NAND" :
    dynamic_cast<NOR*>(pComponent) != nullptr ? "NOR" :
    dynamic_cast<NOT*>(pComponent) != nullptr ? "NOT" :
    dynamic_cast<OR*>(pComponent) != nullptr ? "OR" :
    dynamic_cast<XNOR*>(pComponent) != nullptr ? "XNOR" :
    dynamic_cast<XOR*>(pComponent) != nullptr ? "XOR" : ""
;
```

This works, but I feel like there should be a better way to do this. Perhaps create some kind of map with a reference to the class type of `pComponent` as key and the related string as value?

All classes (AND, NAND, etc) inherit the same base class, `Node`. I have been thinking about adding the following code to Node:

```
virtual std::string get_gate() const = 0;
```

Then have every derived class implement the method, returning its string and call:

```
pComponent->get_gate();
```

Would this solution use memory for every class instance rather than once per class? For example I declare two objects of `AND`, would both of them allocate memory for the method? Will the compiler do something smart?

Comment: If a class or any of its ancestors has a virtual function, you get a vptr in each object of that class, so there's overhead compared to an object with no virtual functions at all. Once you have at least one virtual function in the class or an ancestor, adding another virtual function won't add any per-object overhead (at least with the usual way of implementing C++).

Comment: I see that you tagged this question as [tag:compiler]. Could you tell us more about the language that this code helps to compile?

Comment: Just use a virtual function, chances are even if you end up paying the cost of the vtable it's only 4 or 8 bytes per object to add a vtable and to be honest most likely it will not matter and you probably already have a vtable if you are deleting by base class pointer. Don't worry about it.

Comment: @200_success I added this tag because I figured users interested in compilers know or want to know whether the compiler optimises the code to use less memory per object.

Answer (score 3):

> Would this solution use memory for every class instance rather than once per class?

Depends on whether your class already contains a vtable pointer or not.

If it does, there will be no additional memory requirements per instance (just another entry in the vtable, which is shared by all instances).

If it doesn't, each class will need an additional vtable pointer (that will be automatically inserted by the compiler to make virtual dispatch work). Also, a vtable will be generated, but those are one per class.

However, since you are already using (and that includes possibly deleting) instances of derived classes via pointer to base class, the base classes destructor (in this case `Node::~Node()`) should already be marked `virtual` so the derived classes destructor gets called correctly when deleting the `Node*`. This means each class should already have a vtable anyways - so no additional per-instance overhead.

Comment: Also note, for `dynamic_cast` or `typeid` tricks, the compiler either needs to be able to prove the type at compile-time or fall back to rather complex constructs (possibly requiring per-instance memory, though not necessarily in the objects themselves). So there will be a cost to pay in any case. You could try templates, but then you'd have other problems (like exploding compilation times, or nesting limits, or ...).

Comment: Neither `dynamic_cast` nor `typeid` require "per-instance" memory. Per-class-type, yes; but not per-instance. Not in the objects themselves, and not elsewhere. Nowhere. I hope this clears that up. :)

Comment: @Quuxplusone: `typeid` and `dynamic_cast` require a vtable pointer in order to get the 
`type_info`/check whether a downcast to `Derived*` is possible. This vtable pointer is "per-instance" memory on polymorphic classes. `dynamic_cast` is kinda cheeky, as it fails at compile time if there's no vtable ("use `static_cast` instead"). `typeid` silently does the "wrong thing" (it returns the `type_info` of the current representation) if there's no vtable. Ergo, if your class doesn't have a vtable, those tricks won't work. To fix that, you'd need to introduce a vtable = per-instance memory.

Comment: Just try `class Base{}; class Derived : public Base {}; int main() { Derived d; Base *b = &d; if(dynamic_cast<Derived*>(b) != nullptr) /*compile error*/ {} std::cout << typeid(*b).name(); /* prints type of Base, not Derived */ }`

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
class Gate
{
    virtual void print(std::ostream& out = std::cout) = 0;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, Gate const& gate)
    {
        gate->print(stream);
        return stream;
    }
};
class AndGate
{
    virtual void print(std::ostream& out = std::cout) override {out << "AND";}
    .... Stuff
};
.... etc

int main()
{
    AndGate  gate(g1, g2);
    std::cout << gate << "\n";
}
```

Comment: It might be inconvenient to have to stream into a `std::ostringstream` every time you need the value as a string!

Comment: @TobySpeight: Thats how `boost::lexical_cast<>` works.

Comment: Ah, thanks - I probably ought to take a tourist trip round Boostland sometime soon!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to do exactly what you suggested. Starting from:

```
std::string gate = 
    dynamic_cast<AND*>(pComponent) != nullptr ? "AND" :
    dynamic_cast<NAND*>(pComponent) != nullptr ? "NAND" :
    dynamic_cast<NOR*>(pComponent) != nullptr ? "NOR" :
    dynamic_cast<NOT*>(pComponent) != nullptr ? "NOT" :
    dynamic_cast<OR*>(pComponent) != nullptr ? "OR" :
    dynamic_cast<XNOR*>(pComponent) != nullptr ? "XNOR" :
    dynamic_cast<XOR*>(pComponent) != nullptr ? "XOR" : ""
;
```

You want a virtual method `pComponent->get_gate()` that evaluates to `"AND"` in one case, `"NAND"` in another, and so on. What is the type of `"AND"`, `"NAND"`, and so on? It's `const char *`. (Yes, yes, technically it's `char[4]` and `char[5]` respectively, but not for our purposes here. :)) So:

```
class Node {
public:
    virtual const char *get_gate() const { return ""; }
};

class AND : public Node {
public:
    const char *get_gate() const override { return "AND"; }
};

std::string gateName(Node *pComponent) {
    return pComponent->get_gate();
}
```

---

However, there's an even simpler approach, *if* you just want an identifying string and don't care that it's implementation-defined. Try this:

```
class Node {
public:
    virtual ~Node() = default;
};

class AND : public Node {};

std::string gateName(Node *pComponent) {
    return typeid(*pComponent).name();
}
```

On Linux/Unix/OS X platforms using Clang or GCC, this gives the strings `"4Node"` and `"3AND"`; that is, it gives the *mangled* class names. On Visual Studio, it gives the strings `"class Node"` and `"class AND"`.

Using a virtual function `get_gate` will be marginally faster than the `typeid` approach (by literally 1 or 2 machine instructions). So it's just a question of how quick-and-dirty you want to be. Since you care enough to ask here, you should *probably* spend the extra time and lines-of-code to do the `get_gate` approach; it'll be easier to understand down the road.

---

Even sticking with the multi-way-branch approach, you'll find that it's much faster to use `typeid` than to use `dynamic_cast`, on current library implementations.

```
std::string gate = 
    typeid(*pComponent) == typeid(AND) ? "AND" :
    typeid(*pComponent) == typeid(NAND) ? "NAND" :
    typeid(*pComponent) == typeid(NOR) ? "NOR" :
    typeid(*pComponent) == typeid(NOT) ? "NOT" :
    typeid(*pComponent) == typeid(OR) ? "OR" :
    typeid(*pComponent) == typeid(XNOR) ? "XNOR" :
    typeid(*pComponent) == typeid(XOR) ? "XOR" : ""
;
```

This has different behavior from the original if for example `NAND` inherits from `AND`; but I'm sure from context that that's not the case.

---

This would be a decent use for [X-Macros](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c-x-macros/184401387).

```
std::string gateName(Node *pComponent) {
    return (
#define X(K) typeid(pComponent) == typeid(K) ? #K :
#include "gate-types.h"
#undef X
        ""
    );
}
```

Comment: Why use `char*` in C++? Wouldn't `std::string` be a more natural choice?

Comment: Short answer: *No.*  Longer answer: `std::string` does heap allocation, and we don't need that here.

Comment: `std::string` only does heap allocations for large strings (>12 bytes, maybe more, depending on implementation).

Comment: Why not `std::string_view`?